# How to set Foreign Key Constraint in Cakephp 3.3 Migration?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-migration, phinx

I am new to Cakephp and building an application with Cakephp3.3, I am working on Migrations, I have to create a `user_infos` table, and want to add a new column `user_id`, I am able to add new columns through migrations but I don't know how to add foreign key.

here is my migration file

```
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('user_infos');
        $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 11,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('title', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('created', 'datetime', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('modified', 'datetime', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your migration seems to be based on `Phinx`; you can find relevant methods in `Phinx\Db\Table`. Add

```
->addIndex(['user_id'])
->addForeignKey('user_id', 'users', 'id')
```

to your migration for the constraint on the `users` table.

Comment: hi thanks, but how can we set On delete cascade for the same?

Comment: Would this count as an association?

Answer (score 2):

In Phinx, you can use the below code to add foreign key with cascading

```
$table->addForeignKey('user_id', 'users', 'id', ['delete'=> 'CASCADE', 'update'=> 'CASCADE']);
```